# How to insert int variable to firebase with swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase

I am creating a mobile application that gets data from a firebase database in form of strings

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get username
                let value1 = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let username1 = value1?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                let balance1 = value1?["balance"] as? String ?? ""
```

I have to create some calculations with the balance and so i converted the balance to an integer

```
// Calculate the new balance
                guard let bal = Int(balance1) else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
                let amt = self.amtString
                let intamt = Int(amt)
                //fix math

                let newBalance1 = bal - intamt!
```

Then finally, after the calculation, i have to pass the data back to the firebase database

```
 self.ref.child("users").child(userID!).setValue(["username": username1, "balance": newBalance1])
```

This works fine but the problem is, it goes into the database as an integer and removes the quotes . I have tried

```
let newBalance1 = "\(bal - intamt!)"
```

But for some reason, this alters the calculation and gives a completely different value .  Please i need help converting the integer to string without altering the calculation.

Comment: Try "\\(newBalance1)" or use `stringWithFormat` to convert this into `String`.

Comment: I have tried "\(newBalance1)" while passing it to firebase but that also alters the calculation somehow.

Comment: What is the problem with `integer`? If it is a balance it should be number... So why you want to save this as `String`?

Comment: If i save it to firebase as an integer, firebase brings it back out as a string and since the quotation marks are missing, it comes as nil .

Comment: `No` this is not true! If you will save this as `integer` you will get this as `integer` because `firebase` keeps everything in `json` form.

Comment: You just need to update this line `let balance1 = value1?["balance"] as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: okay let me give that a try

Comment: for some reason when i do 500 - 1 with that method, it gives a solution of 476

Comment: Its Wired! If you don't mind can you send your code so that I can check the issue in it because If I make sample here probably issue would not come.

Comment: Sure, how can i send it to you?

Comment: Upload on dropbox and give me that link.

Answer (score 0):

The approach on this may be the issue. If you need the number as an int, store it as an int.

This line of code...

> self.ref.child("users").child(userID!).setValue(["username":
>   username1, "balance": newBalance1])

...does not "remove the quotes". newBalance1 is defined as an *integer* in your code (there are no quotes to start with) and this line writes the integer.... as an integer.

If  you want to convert it to a String and write the string out to Firebase, this code will do it.

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userID!)
        .setValue(["username": username1, "balance": String(newBalance1)])
```

I ran both of those lines and the results are

```
users
  some_uid
    balance:  123 //this is an Int from your code
    username: "some username"
```

and

```
users
  some_uid
    balance:  "123" //this is a string from my code
    username: "some username"
```

It's not clear in the question why you need strings - in general if you are working with Ints, leave them as Ints as, for example, it makes sorting work properly

Sorting a series of strings "1", "2", "3", "10" will results in

```
1
10
2
3
```

whereas if they are Int's they will sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was never the int or string. Those were always correct but the code was looping and thus repeating the calculations multiple times till i manually dismissed it, this was the reason for the inconsistent incorrect answers .